# How can download the mongodb not from its org site

Tags: mongodb

I am new with Mongodb and I want to install it on windows 7. All the solution guide to this link [1](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#atlas)
but when I click download it does not work is there any solution to download from other site?

Comment: Did you clear your cache yet? Maybe try another browser. Make sure to select community server & Windows

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work" -- is there any error message in your browser? What browser version are you using? If you are using any ad blocking software, try disabling this before visiting the MongoDB download page.

Comment: I am using chrom and I tried with internet explorer but it is the same thing it does not generate any error in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have apparently problems with the main download center, but no acess problem to the domain itself, you can try the direct MongoDB binaries links listed below. I added other platforms for sake of completeness.

**Windows (64 bits) :** https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl

**Windows (32 bits) :** https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386

**MacOS :** https://www.mongodb.org/dl/osx

**Linux (64 bits):** https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64

**Linux (32 bits):** https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/i386

Comment: I used your first link but I think it dectects automatically the version of your windows I mean if it is 32 or 64 any way thank you